# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' парсинг

Tags: python, requests, bs4

пытаюсь спарсить курс btc с binance, но почему-то выдают ошибку.Такой тег существует, можете проверить.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HOST = "https://www.binance.com"
URL = "https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/BTC_USDT"    

r = requests.get(URL).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")

course = soup.find("div", class_="showPrice").text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный класс формируется динамически и постоянно меняется и с помощью requests ее значение получить не получится. Для данной задачи лучше использовать selenium webdriver, которая эммулирует открытие браузера и при этом с ее помощью также динамичести можно будет получать актуальный курс, а не на момент обращения к странице.